# Como cambio el color

Tags: css

Muy buenas a todos yo quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar.

Tengo este CSS y quiero cambiar mi color de fondo por... `#180833` y no se como, gracias por adelantado Xoxo

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800');

body{
    background: #f6f5f7; 
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #3E363F;
}
```

Comment: Cambia **background: #f6f5f7;** por **background: #180833;**

Comment: Saber inglés es útil para intuir qué debes cambiar.

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `background` te sirve para ponerle propiedades referentes al Background pero si lo que buscas solamente es cambiar tu color de fondo te sugiero utilizar `background-color`. Quedaría:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800');

body{
    background-color: #180833; 
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #3E363F;
}
```